# Is there a simpler way to erase the end of the line using cat in R?

Tags: r

I like to do use this in my scripts:

```
cat("Saving...")
do_something_slow()
cat("\rSaved\n")
```

The problem is that the carriage return is applied without erasing the rest of the line, so I get this:

```
Savedg...
```

To fix it I can do:

```
cat("\rSaved\033[K\n")
```

but it's kind of ugly. Is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I like to use `message()` instead of `cat()` for generating messages.  For example:

`cat("Saving..."); cat("\rSaved\n")`

returns:

```
Savdg...
```

While:

`message("Saving..."); message("\rSaved\n")`

returns:

```
Saving...
Saved
```

**Edit:**

Inspired by @gauden answer, another function could be:

```
replaceMessage <- function(x, width = 80)
{
    message("\r", rep(" ", times = width - length(x)), "\r", appendLF = F)
    message(x, appendLF = F)
}
```

And then:

```
replaceMessage("Saving..."); Sys.sleep(1); replaceMessage("Saved\n")
```

**Note:**

While `replaceMessage()` behaves as expected in Linux and Rterm on Windows, it behaves strangely in my Rgui (2.15.0, Windows x64). Specifically, `Saving...` is never displayed, and after `Saved` is displayed, the cursor is moved `width` spaces (in the example, 80 spaces) to the right. I am not sure why.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about message. I guess I could do `message("Saving...", appendLF=F); message("\rSaved")`, but I would still have the same problem

Comment: I missed your point that you want to overwrite the line. I suppose you could try `message("Saving...", appendLF=F); message("\r    Saved")`, but that's still not quite what you are after.

Comment: @nochocab Taking inspiration from gauden, I added a little function which might be closer to what you want.

Comment: I like it. I might do `message("\r", rep(" ", times = width - length(x)), "\r", appendLF= F)` instead

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you want the messages to all appear serially on one line, how about something whimsical?

```
cleancat <- function(astring, width=80) {
    # Reserves a line of 80 (default) characters
    # and uses it for serial updates
    require("stringr")
    astring <- paste("\r", astring, sep="")
    cat(str_pad(astring, 80, "right"))
    # pretend to do something slow
    # delete this line if cleancat is used in production
    Sys.sleep(0.5) 
}

# imitate printing a series of updates
test <- lapply(c("Saving -", 
                 "Saving \\", 
                 "Saving |", 
                 "Saving /", 
                 "Saving -", 
                 "Saving \\", 
                 "Saving |", 
                 "Saving /", 
                 "Saved"), cleancat)
```

Of course, you would need to load the `stringr` package and set up the `cleancat` function in your environment which you might think is even uglier...

Comment: Clever. I was looking for something a bit simpler, though. Interesting, anyway.